# Possible to style the bicycling route colour for Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I have the following code to display the bicycling layer in Google Maps. But I wondered if it is possible to change the dark green colour to another colour?

I have tried setting the strokeColor is var mapOptions but this didn't seem to work.

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.231472, -0.539783);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
  bikeLayer.setMap(map);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: there currently is no option to apply a custom style